# sql server: how to execute a .sql from another query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a .sql script with a lot of action queries that work on some staging tables.  This script needs to be run twice with some other commands in-between i.e.:

1. Load the staging table from source A
2. Use `do_stuff.sql` to process it
3. Move the results somewhere.
4. Repeat Steps 1-3 for source B.

The brute force approach would be to just copy & paste dostuff.sql as needed.  While this would technically work, is there a better way?

I'm hoping there's a command like `RunThisSQL 'C:\do_stuff.sql'` that I haven't discovered yet.

#### Update

Well, it's been about 5 years and I just re-discovered this old question.  I did this recently and made a cursor to loop thru a master table.  For each record in that master table, the script runs through an inner script using variables set by the master table.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/

Comment: Why don't you convert that file to a stored procedure?

Comment: How are you executing the script? One method would be to write a batch/PowerShell routine which runs `sqlcmd` with your script, something like `sqlcmd -SMyServer -ido_stuff.sql`

Comment: @voithos, I'm running this manually from within MS SQL Server Management Studio. In other words, open the .sql file and hit Execute.

Comment: Try this cmd **@'C:/do_stuff.sql';** in sql command promte. This works in Oracle.

Comment: The problem is that the SQL code, when it's actually running, is running on the *server*. It no longer has any (real) relationship with the SSMS instance that *sent* the query to the server, other than the connection. And there's nothing build into TDS to allow it to somehow request a new file to be loaded and sent over that connection.

Comment: You can look at [SSIS](https://www.google.lt/search?q=ssis&aq=f&oq=ssis&aqs=chrome.0.59j65l3j60l2.1225j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) If you have in your server.

Comment: Hi all, this all sounds like good advice I'll want to try when I have the time. But I was in a time crunch yesterday.  @DanBracuk, I went with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you use visual studio you can create "Sql Server Database" project. Withing the project you can create script that let you execute your *.sql files in a manner

```
 /*
Post-Deployment Script Template                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 This file contains SQL statements that will be appended to the build script.       
 Use SQLCMD syntax to include a file in the post-deployment script.         
 Example:      :r .\myfile.sql                              
 Use SQLCMD syntax to reference a variable in the post-deployment script.       
 Example:      :setvar TableName MyTable                            
               SELECT * FROM [$(TableName)]                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
```

see also. http://candordeveloper.com/2013/01/08/creating-a-sql-server-database-project-in-visual-studio-2012/

Answer (score 2):

Try using xp_cmdshell.

```
 EXEC xp_cmdshell  'sqlcmd -S ' + @ServerName + ' -d ' + @DBName + ' -i ' +@FileName
```

Answer (score 1):

xp_cmdshell and concatenation do not play together nicely, often resulting in an "Incorrect syntax near '+'" error. So further to [Jeotics](http://Jeotics) solution above you will need to make a variable of the entire string you pass to xp_cmdshell (including quotes around anything that may contain a space (eg filepath\filename). This is mentioned in the Microsoft documentation for xp_cmdshell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments). Other issues you will have to contend with are the default set up for SQL Server which has xp_cmdshell disabled as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/xp-cmdshell-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017) and granting permission to non-system administrators to use xp_cmdshell outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions). The documentation generally advises against giving xp_cmdshell rights to too many people owing to it being a vehicle for those with malintent but if, like me, you have minimal and trustworthy database users then it seems like a reasonable solution. One last issue that requires correct configuration is the SQL Server Agent as outlined [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/70069/how-do-i-give-file-system-access-to-sql-servers-sqlserveragent-virtual-account/125638#125638). Documentation outlines that SQL Agent is responsible for background scheduling (such as back ups) and performance of command line statements, etc..

```
DECLARE
    @Server nvarchar (50)
    ,@Database nvarchar(50)
    ,@File nvarchar(100)
    ,@cmd nvarchar(300);

SET @Server = server_name;
SET @Database = database_name;
SET @File = 'C:\your file path with spaces';
SET @cmd = 'sqlcmd -S ' + @Server + ' -d ' + @Database + ' i "' + @File + '"';

EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some security issues with enabling xp_cmdshell in SQL Server. You can create a CLR Stored procedure, which executes the passed file content. This CLR stored procedure is especially for this purpose, not like xp_cmdshell, which can do anything over the command prompt.

[issues with enabling xp_cmdshell](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/2009/11/13/why-we-recommend-against-xp-cmdshell/)

[Create CLR stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/execute-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017)